# Adding a dynamic input into an Angular 5 component

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 5 component that has an input like so:

```
<my-component [myVariable]="test"></my-component>
```

How can I make "test" be equal to a property on the page?

If I try:

```
<my-component [myVariable]="{{randomvariable}}"></my-component>
```

I get: 'Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular%5D+Got+interpolation+%28%7B%7B%7D%7D%29+where+expression+was+expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use {{}}.
just use variables which are defined in .ts

```
<my-component [myVariable]="randomvariable"></my-component>
```